# Как сделать положение виджетов динамическим в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qscrollarea, qgridlayout

Как сделать, чтобы при увеличении или уменьшении окна виджеты соответственно меняли своё расположение/размеры (желательно еще и в определенных пределах).

Чем можно воспользоваться для достижения такого результата?

Нужно ли для этого создавать отдельный метод, либо просто использовать **`блочный`** или **`сеточный`** **`макет`** вместо **`абсолютного позиционирования`**?

Допустим, есть такой вот код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout

import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 975, 795)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #24232d;")


        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #fff;")
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumSize(970, 400)
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(485, 200)

        self.choose_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.choose_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 480, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.choose_btn.setFont(font)
        self.choose_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                      "    border: 1px solid #fff;\n"
                                      "    color: #fff;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.choose_btn.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 480, 61, 31))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff;")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

        self.open_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.open_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 480, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.open_btn.setFont(font)
        self.open_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "    border: 1px solid #fff;\n"
                                    "    color: #fff;\n"
                                    "}")
        self.open_btn.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.scrollArea, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.hbox1.addStretch(0)

        self.hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.open_btn)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.choose_btn)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.comboBox)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addSpacing(50)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox1, 1)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2, 2)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что нужно добавить для того, чтобы `scrollArea` не прилипала к левой стороне и находилась всегда сверху, а также изменяла свои размеры пропорционально (в дальнейшем просто планирую размещать там большое изображение); между кнопками появилось пространство и они стали меньше?

Конечный вариант того, что я хотел бы видеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: pythoncoder, абсолютного позиционирование не подходит для этих целей. Покажите ваш код и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать, и я попродую вам помочь.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout, QWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 975, 795)
        self.resize(975, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #24232d;")

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #fff;")
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumSize(970, 400)
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(485, 200)
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("background-color: #24237d;")

        self.choose_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('choose_btn')
#        self.choose_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 480, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.choose_btn.setFont(font)
        self.choose_btn.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                border: 1px solid #fff;
                color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.choose_btn.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
#        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 480, 61, 31))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff;")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem('comboBox:') 

        self.open_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('open_btn')
#        self.open_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 480, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.open_btn.setFont(font)
        self.open_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                    "    border: 1px solid #fff;\n"
                                    "    color: #fff;\n"
                                    "}")
        self.open_btn.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.widget = QWidget()                                      # +++ self.widget
        self.widget.setMaximumWidth(970)                             # +++
        self.hbox2 = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)                        # +++ self.widget
        self.hbox2.setContentsMargins(0, 5, 0, 0)                    # +++
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.open_btn)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.choose_btn)
        self.hbox2.addStretch()                                      # +++
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.comboBox)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)                              # +++ QGridLayout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 2, 1, 1, 1) 
        
        self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 2)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 0)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 100)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё работает! Премного благодарен! :) Если не секрет, из каких источников черпаете информацию по Qt? Только из документации? Возможно, есть какие-нибудь книги?

Comment: @pythoncoder я просматриваю все, чтобы не пропустить какие-нибудь оригинальные решения, но лучше документации ничего нет (Layout Management  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Да и сильно не расстраивайтесь если сразу будет не легко разобраться с документацией, со временем все наладится.